# How to build .so file from existing VS2019 (.exe) project for android (Xamarin)?

Tags: c++, xamarin.android, shared-libraries, visual-studio-2019, .so

I'm working on android project, and I am trying to use some c++ project on github.

How can I compile this project to make shared library (*.so) file that I can use in android Xamarin project?

Comment: You can refer to this thread about using C++ libraries with Xamarin.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/